# Javascript or Jquery - Accordion menus. Can a menu option ignore link but still expand/collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a programmer, but need some advice on an accordion menu.

At the moment, I have an accordion menu that doesn't expand/collapse as the `li` elements that have children also link to pages. So when you select a parent `li`, it opens the page, but doesn't expand the sub-menu of the accordion.

Due to other complications, I can't change the code of the `li` elements - the parent `li` elements have to have an `a href` link in their code.

Is it possible to get the browser to ignore the links of these 'parent' `li` and just expand/collapse?

Comment: Yes, using `preventDefault` on the `click` event. `$('.some_link').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Thanks. I will pass that on to the person doing the script.

Comment: The developer says that won't work because it only works on the same page. I have a sort of tri-pane layout, where the accordion menu is in the left, and the targets for the links in the menu are loaded into the middle column.